# Wondershare MobileGo connect from PC behind NAT

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have noticed that that both PC and Android phone need to be in the same network to connect  using Wondershare MobileGo by wifi.

Which ports are using by Wondershare MobileGo to connect and data transfer? Maybe simple port forwarding can be set in Router configuration and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows go to Start -> Run -> cmd (right click Run as Administrator)

```
netstat -b -a >> c:\PortLists.txt
```

A few minutes later the command would be finished.

Open the file and search "Mobile" word.

```
[svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:7765           *:*                    
 [MobileGoService.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:41481          *:*                    
 [BitTorrent.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:60337          *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*
```

Here is my result:

```
[MobileGoService.exe] UDP    0.0.0.0:41481
```